# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0. label to string

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf

What does this error mean? I am trying to retrieve the date from a label and display it on a wpf form.

```
          printResident.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse( lblDOB.ToString() );
```

This method calls the retrieve method that executes the sql select from the database to reteive the information onto the form.+

```
          ResidentData.Retrieve(printResident.ResidentID);
```

Comment: What's the value of `lblDOB.ToString()`?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus {01/01/0001 00:00:00}

Comment: What type is `lblDOB`?

Comment: Label? but its database value is DateTime

Comment: How are you assigning the value to the `lblDOB`?

Answer (score 7):

As a guess, you're using a `Label` directly.  Try doing `lblDOB.Content.ToString()` instead.

Comment: No such property exists for Label

Comment: @user2122032 Updated.  Didn't notice it was WPF.

Comment: I did:  printResident.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(lblDOB1.Content.ToString()); but got object is not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Based on the information in the comments, you're getting back a DateTime value from your DB that may be invalid, and how you're assigning the value to the label is unclear - `lblDOB.Content` should only throw a null reference exception if you haven't assigned to it.

Comment: No they are the same. I just forgot to add the '1' infront of lblDOB

Comment: I have assigned it the object Resident printResident = new Resident();

Comment: @user2122032 Specifically, what do you have assigned to `lblDOB1`?  Is there somewhere you have `lblDOB1 = ??` or `lblDOB1.Content = ??`?

Comment: Ah! I havent set the content!

Comment: @user2122032 Did that work for you?  If so, please mark the question answered.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `lblDOB` is a label, you'll need to use:

```
lblDOB.Content.ToString();
```

Initially, you were using `lblDOB.ToString()`, which returns a string representation of your label *(probably something like System.Windows.Controls.Label, followed by the content of your label)*, not something that `DateTime.Parse` would be able to work with.

Now you're trying to use `lblDOB.Content.ToString()`, which is the correct way, but you're getting a null reference exception. Place a breakpoint on the statement that loads the date from the database into your label and make sure it's working, because it's complaining that `lblDOB.Content` has no value.

Answer (score 0):

May be this Helps:-

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001 00:00:00");
            label1.Content = dt.ToString();
```